# TFS Build Gated Check-In - Need to Select from Multiple Build Definitions

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, alm, tfvc

I got two build definition that is mapped to some common folders. When I do check in it prompts me the selection box to pick up either of the build definition.

It gives me the option. Can I change my build definition to select the default based on what is triggered and show it as the first option without need for user to select the right one?

[image: Check in prompt]

Comment: 'Select the default based on what is triggered'? Can you explain what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two build definitions configured for the same source control folder then you will always get a choice. There is no way to set a default.

It is recommended to have only one gated-checkin configured to avoid confusion.